# Show that $\lim \sin(xy)/xy =1$ when $(x,y)$ tends to $(0,0)$

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

I have started by proving that $\lim \sin x/x =1$ when $x$ tends to zero, using trigonometric arguments. Now I should use these arguments to prove it with two variables, but I have to relate the magnitude of the vector $(x,y)$ to the product of its coordinates.